# Low cold water pressure

Tags: pipe

On Sunday night my pipes froze.  When I woke up on Monday morning a pipe had burst in my well house area.  I had a pipe fitter come out and fix it. Ever since then, I have low water pressure in both of my bathroom sinks and bathroom bathtubs. Also my washer must have low pressure to because when I try to do laundry it starts the cycle then says LF and wont finish. The toilets won't fill or flush unless you fill it manually.

Comment: Welcom to DIY: maybe your plumber fitted pipes that were too thin

Comment: Is there anyplace in your  house where the pressure is NOT low?